# ImGui visual glitch

Tags: c++, glfw, imgui

So, I implemented ImGUi with docking in GLFW window and all was perfect while was only the Demo Window. When I put one more, that happened:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z4lf.png)

Any idea? I don't know if I should put the code since it's inside a class with other functions. But for ImGui, it's just the code from opengl3 glfw example

Comment: Its going to be pretty hard to help you without any code. An MVCE is pretty much necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably this known issue:
https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/4832